# Lost Emails "Windows Live Mail"

Tags: windows-live-mail

Had a power failure, computer shut down.When power restored computer started up but went through many functions before starting. All "Windows Live Mail" folders and messages have disappeared

Comment: What "many" functions exactly?

Comment: Windows 7 Black screen with many,many rolling lines of description stating what computer was doing to change/restore settins. scrolling was too fast to read.

Comment: Yes I have tried a restore point 2 days ago before power outage.      NO Luck